# Conversão array em string

Tags: php, array, string

Tenho a seguinte array como transformo ela em uma string.
Essa string seria usada para salvar os produtos do carrinho de compras no MySQL. Então têm vários lanches e produtos:

produtos `5,2,5` uso esse codigo `implode(',', $adicional);`

agora os opcionais

```
8#-2:7#-1,8#-2:7#-1,8#-2:7#-1
```

cada, e um lanche e o seu opcional

```
array
(
    [8] => -2
    [7] => -1
)

string: 8#-2:7#-1 // preciso da string de esse formato
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem várias maneiras de se fazer isso. Seguem algumas possibilidades:

**Versão 1**

```
$saida = '';
$cola = '';
foreach( $minhaarray as $chave => $valor ) {
   $saida .= $cola.$chave.'#'.$valor;
   $cola=':';
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hLAeYA)**

**Versão 2**

```
$saida = implode(
   ':',
   array_map(
      function( $valor, $chave ) { return $chave.'#'.$valor; },
      $minhaarray,
      array_keys( $minhaarray )
   )
);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/RVq23C)**

Comment: perfeito :D muito obrigado bacco