# Converter string array para string em VB

Tags: .net, string, vb.net

Preciso usar o SPLIT em vários dados, mas preciso converter a array string para string pra isso.

Estou colocando String() para receber a variável da array string, mas o VS continua me dizendo que array de uma dimensão não pode ser convertido para string.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Conversão array em string](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33530/convers%c3%a3o-array-em-string)

Comment: Dá uma olhada na função [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), que pode ser usada para converter arrays em uma única string.

Comment: Coloque seu código,faça um [mcve].

Comment: @VictorGomes parece que linkou algo errado, a pergunta aqui é sobre vb.net e não php =)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) que espera um separador e paramêtros para concatenar e retornar uma string (uma coleção em geral). Exemplo:

```
Dim result as String = String.Join("", array)
```

Comment: Ele concatena sem separadores?

Comment: Sim, desde que você informe que o separador é uma string vazia, `String.Empty`.

Comment: Certo... Ele me retorna intacto? Sem modificações?

Answer (score 2):

Catharina, não está muito clara a situação que você tem, por isso é difícil dar uma resposta categórica.

Para concatenar itens de um array em um só String, sem separadores, você pode usar o método [String.Concat()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=PT-BR&k=k%28System.String.Concat%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

Para concatenar itens de um array em um só string, incluindo um string de separação, o método, já indicado por outros, é [Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=PT-BR&k=k%28Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Join%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

Para completar com itens de um array uma string preformatada, o método preferível é [String.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=PT-BR&k=k%28System.String.Format%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

Agora, você mencionou que precisa usar o *SPLIT* e eu não entendi, porque [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=PT-BR&k=k%28System.String.Split%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true) faz exatamente o contrário: divide um String em vários fragmentos e retorna um Array.

Abaixo coloco alguns exemplos. Se você colocar seu código aqui, facilita bastante dar uma resposta.

```
Sub ExemplosStringArray()
    Dim arrayOfString As String() = {"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"}
    Dim concatStrings = String.Concat(arrayOfString)
    MsgBox(concatStrings)
    Dim joinedStrings = Join(arrayOfString, ";")
    MsgBox(joinedStrings)
    Dim formattedString = String.Format("Temos {0}, {1} e finalmente {2}", arrayOfString)
    MsgBox(formattedString)
    Dim multipartString = "dddd-eeee+ffff"  
    Dim arrayFromString = multipartString.Split("-"c, "+"c)
    Dim newStringFromArray = Join(arrayFromString, vbCrLf)
    MsgBox(newStringFromArray)
End Sub
```